# Grouping and Plotting Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi Am am having trouble grouping and graphing/plotting data with.

```
    signed  last_seen                           mon
0   Signed  2022-09-07 00:18:14.149000+00:00    9
1   Signed  2022-09-01 06:19:11.571000+00:00    9
2   Signed  2022-09-07 00:18:14.142000+00:00    9
3   Signed  2022-09-07 00:43:10.486000+00:00    9
4   Signed  2022-09-07 01:02:54.170000+00:00    9
... ... ... ...
995 Unsigned    2022-08-31 01:37:44.696000+00:00    8
996 Unsigned    2022-08-31 01:37:44.682000+00:00    8
997 Unsigned    2022-08-31 01:37:44.683000+00:00    8
998 Unsigned    2022-08-31 02:48:17.310000+00:00    8
999 Unsigned    2022-09-06 09:29:33.890000+00:00    9
1000 rows × 3 columns
```

I get this using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
f = open('binary.json', "r")
data = json.loads(f.read())
data
df = pd.json_normalize(data['results'])
drop_list = ["last_seen","signed"]
df = df.drop(df.columns.difference(drop_list), axis=1)
df.last_seen = pd.to_datetime(df.last_seen)
df['mon'] = df.last_seen.dt.month
```

I now cannot work out how to group by month and signed status.

I then need to plot this on a stacked bar chart. The bars will hold signed v unsigned grouped by month.

Can anyone please help me out??

Comment: Apply  groupby https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas-dataframe-groupby and .plot.bar https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html#pandas-dataframe-plot-bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group the data by `month` and "unstack" signed column into columns for each label:

```py
df_grp = df.groupby(['mon', 'signed'])['mon'].count().unstack('signed')

>>  signed  Signed  Unsigned
>>  mon                     
>>  8            2         4
>>  9            3         1
```

Plot stacked bar chart using pandas plot API:

```py
df_grp[['Signed','Unsigned']].plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

[image]